# Strange screen on MacBook Air (2016)

Tags: macbook-pro, catalina

Recently my MacBook Air (2016) has been randomly giving me this screen. Longest it’s ever lasted was a minute. One time I had to shut down the computer to get it to go away, another time it went away on its own. Does anyone know if there is a quick fix?

[image]

Comment: Why the assumption that Catalina is the problem?  And if it is, why tag it Yosemite?

Comment: When that happens, take a screenshot.  If  the image is  clear, you have a hardware problem.  Additionally, you should book it up to an screenshot external monitor to see if it occurs there too.

Comment: Have you tried NRAM reset? https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204063

Answer (score 1):

**Reset NVRAM or PRAM on your Mac**

Settings that can be stored in NVRAM include sound volume, display resolution, startup disk selection, time zone, and recent kernel panic information. The settings stored in NVRAM depend on your Mac and the devices that you're using with your Mac.

Shut down your Mac, then turn it on and immediately press and hold these four keys together: <kbd>Option</kbd>, <kbd>Command</kbd>, <kbd>P</kbd>, and <kbd>R</kbd>. You can release the keys after about 20 seconds, during which your Mac might appear to restart.

Answer (score -1):

this happens some time to time, at least with my macbook air which is a year younger then yours. i found this to happen when switching to fullscreen or airplay. also since that time my computer needs a replacement. my suggestion is: that you get a good refurbished mac.